# How can I get static files to work in my Django project?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-settings

#### Using: Python 3.7 and Django 2.1.4

I'm working through the tutorials in William S. Vincent's [Django for Beginners](https://djangoforbeginners.com/) book. I'm in the "Blog App" part of the book, and I've been following his instructions to the letter. However, I cannot seem to get the dev server to serve my static CSS file, no matter what I do.

[My source code can be found here.](https://bitbucket.org/cmsteffen/django-blog/src/master/)

I'm using `manage.py runserver` to run a development demo server for local testing.

Here's my directory tree:

```
./
├── blog
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── blog_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── static
│   └── css
│       └── base.css
└── templates
    ├── base.html
    └── home.html
```

Originally I updated my `blog_project/settings.py` with this line:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

and I put `{% load static %}` at the top of my `templates/base.html` file, as well as adding `<link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">` in the `<head> ... </head>` section.

After writing the `static/css/base.css` file, this should have worked. But it didn't. I researched the forums and Stack Overflow, and saw people advising adding the static directories to the `blog_project/settings.py` file, so I updated that file, adding the following to the bottom:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICTILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_ROOT,
]
```

Then I updated the `blog_project/urls.py` file, adding two new imports:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
```

and the following line:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

But even this didn't work.

You can check my [settings.py](https://bitbucket.org/cmsteffen/django-blog/src/master/blog_project/settings.py), [urls.py](https://bitbucket.org/cmsteffen/django-blog/src/master/blog_project/urls.py) and [base.html](https://bitbucket.org/cmsteffen/django-blog/src/master/templates/base.html) files to see what I'm talking about.

I expected the `manage.py runserver` to host the static files, but it did not. When I tried to load the CSS file directly, I got a 404 error.

Comment: you should **not** put the `STATIC_ROOT` into your `STATICFILES_DIRS`, also mind how your wrote `STATICFILES_DIRS`, not `staticTiles_dirs`, as you wrote.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that the entire problem was caused by a single typo. When I came back here to update my post, Jojo had already pointed it out. How embarrassing! 

Comment: Typo's are the kind of error you'll never get rid of, no matter how long you program, at least I'm sure that I never will. But the take home message here is also the separation between `STATIC_ROOT` and your `STATICFILE_DIRS`. If you do not keep them separated, the `collectstatic` command will complain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you misspelled your `STATICFILES_DIRS` in the linked `settings.py` file with a rampant T instead of an F: `STATIC`**`T`**`ILES_DIRS`.

Second, do not put your `STATIC_ROOT` anywhere within your `STATICFILES_DIRS`. From the docs:

> **Warning**
>
> This (*`STATIC_ROOT`*) should be an initially empty destination directory for collecting your static files from their permanent locations into one directory for ease of deployment; it is not a place to store your static files permanently. You should do that (*by that they mean 'store your static files'*) in directories that will be found by staticfiles’s finders, which by default, are 'static/' app sub-directories and any directories you include in `STATICFILES_DIRS`).

*Note: cursive text was added by me.*

---

So I recommend the following configuration for your setttings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

As long as you are in debugging mode, `DEBUG=True`, you should be good to go. There is also no need to add the `STATIC_ROOT` to the `urlpatterns` as you did in your `urls.py`. You only want to do that if you don't have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)).

At the moment you want to switch to production, have a look at [how this is done correctly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/deployment/).

*Hope that helped and happy coding!*

Comment: Oh, how embarrassing. STATICTILES? Yeah, of course that didn't work! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ha, no worries! these things happen to me all the time! Glad I could help!